# Getting unauthorized when using Direct Method on a device Module

Tags: android, azure-iot-hub

I am using the azure-iot-sdk-java lib on an Android app, with kotlin. I want to send Direct Method on a module of an iot edge, but get unauthorized error.

We have a web service using azure-iot-sdk-node that work fine, i tried to do the same code in java, but it is not working. We are using exactly the same ConnectionString, DeviceId, ModuleId and Method name.

I'm using this lib

```
implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.19.0'
```

I'm using this code

```
private val moduleClient by lazy {
    ModuleClient(CONNECTION_STRING, IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS).also { it.open() }
}

fun sendMessage() {
    val payload = "/* some payload */"
    moduleClient.invokeMethod(DEVICE_ID, MODULE_ID, MethodRequest(METHOD_NAME, payload))
}
```

I tried with IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT. I tried with the java sample about direct method and our own connection string.
The returned error is

> {
>       "Message": "{\"errorCode\":401002,\"trackingId\":\"2d829ee7a3044dd28d496e512def06ca-G:11-TimeStamp:01/07/2020 16:06:57\",\"message\":\"Unauthorized\",\"timestampUtc\":\"2020-01-07T16:06:57.0613027Z\"}",
>       "ExceptionMessage": ""
>   }

Comment: For invoking a Direct method on the device/method you should use a service-facing endpoint. In other words, you have to use a service SDK package.

Comment: If you are talking about the iot-service-client of the sdk, it doesn't give me the possibility to send direct method, but only messages, and not on a module if i wanted to, only on a device.
The sdk readme clearly says that "Device client SDK" can send direct method.